# PHP cURL POST request taking a long time (over 20 seconds) to complete

Tags: php, curl, post

I am using this PHP code running locally to make a request to a remote address:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
```

The info returned is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [url] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 397
    [request_size] => 316
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 22.844
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.016
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.016
    [size_upload] => 143
    [size_download] => 51819
    [speed_download] => 2268
    [speed_upload] => 6
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 143
    [starttransfer_time] => 22.719
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [local_port] => 64907
)
```

The request does also return a valid response, it's just that it is taking over 20 seconds for the PHP page to load and the `curl_getinfo` seems to suggest that it should not be taking this long.

I've tried a whole range of things to try and fix this but none of them seem to work, sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.

Thanks.

Comment: there are some things matter for this. first net speed of between the servers (or systems). then the latency.

Comment: Perhaps the remote server is sleeping for 20 seconds :/ also the 2kbps download is slow as a snail.

Comment: The remote server is not sleeping for 20 seconds to my knowledge, requests sent otherwise (not via PHP) are fine and load much faster. @LawrenceCherone

Comment: See: https://3v4l.org/Vrh1I

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That does not seem to be the issue. Changing the size it needs to download to 600 instead of the 51000 it was before still results in a 18 second total time.

Comment: Please show the code your pulling from.